# Why are clang.exe and clang++.exe exactly the same?

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I just happened to find that `clang.exe` and `clang++.exe` have exactly the same hash. In fact, there are 2 more: `clang-cl.exe` and `clang-cpp.exe` also share the same hash with the previous two. Each one takes about 80MB, not that small.

Why they make so many aliases for `clang.exe`? Is this unique to Windows or the same for all platforms?

Comment: I assume this is unique to Windows, as Windows does not have the same support for symbolic links as the Unixes do. The behavior of the program may be different, depending on the name by which it is invoked. You often see things like that on Linux, for example with /bin/sh often being a link to /bin/bash, but the first one starts bash in compatibility mode, the latter starts it regularly.

Comment: @Taschi this comment should be a proper answer.

Comment: @arrowd I generally don't like posting assumptions as answers, but here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is unique to Windows, as Windows does not have the same support for symbolic links as the Unixes do. The behavior of the program may be different, depending on the name by which it is invoked. You often see things like that on Linux, for example with /bin/sh often being a link to /bin/bash, but the first one starts bash in compatibility mode, the latter starts it regularly.

Comment: I don't know much about Linux or Unix. So on Linux those symbolic links serve as real aliases, which may convey additional information, instead of being copys of each other? Windows makes copys of them just to abide to the uniform interface?

Comment: Not sure what's `additional information` you are talking about, but everything else is correct.

Comment: Yes, although that additional information really is just "was i called as /bin/sh or /bin/bash". There isn't anything more to these aliases.